# Get all the user info using Microsoft Graph

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, spfx, spfx-webparts, microsoft-graph

How can I get all the user info, from a SPFX WebPart, using Microsoft Graph?

I need to call the API 'https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/' to get the user info from a SPFX WebPart.

I'm using SPFX with React

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the GraphHttpClient provided with the SharePoint Framework is limited at the moment, you have to use ADAL JS instead. You can read more about the approach and it’s considerations at https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/guidance/call-microsoft-graph-from-your-web-part